# Python / Scrapy: CrawlSpider stops after fetching start_urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I have wasted days to get my mind around Scrapy, reading the docs and other Scrapy Blogs and Q&A ... and now I am about to do what men hate most: Ask for directions ;-) The problem is: My spider opens, fetches the start_urls, but apparently does nothing with them. Instead it closes immediately and that was that. Apparently, I do not even get to the first self.log() statement.

What I've got so far is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
# from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse, FormRequest, Request
from KiPieSpider.items import *
from KiPieSpider.settings import *

class KiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "KiSpider"
    allowed_domains = ['www.kiweb.de', 'kiweb.de']
    start_urls = (
        # ST Regra start page:
        'https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=206',
            # follow ST Regra links in the form of:
            # https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=206&page=\d+
            # https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=299&docid=\d{6}
        # ST Thermo start page:
        'https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=202&page=1',
            # follow ST Thermo links in the form of:
            # https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=202&page=\d+ 
            # https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=299&docid=\d{6}
    )
    rules = (
        # First rule that matches a given link is followed / parsed.
        # Follow category pagination without further parsing:
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                # Extract links in the form:
                allow=r'Default\.aspx?pageid=(202|206])&page=\d+',
                # but only within the pagination table cell:
                restrict_xpaths=('//td[@id="ctl04_teaser_next"]'),
            ),
            follow=True,
        ),
        # Follow links to category (202|206) articles and parse them:
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                # Extract links in the form:
                allow=r'Default\.aspx?pageid=299&docid=\d+',
                # but only within article preview cells:
                restrict_xpaths=("//td[@class='TOC-zelle TOC-text']"),
            ),
            # and parse the resulting pages for article content:
            callback='parse_init',
            follow=False,
        ),
    )

    # Once an article page is reached, check whether a login is necessary:
    def parse_init(self, response):
        self.log('Parsing article: %s' % response.url)
        if not response.xpath('input[@value="Logout"]'):
            # Note: response.xpath() is a shortcut of response.selector.xpath()
            self.log('Not logged in. Logging in...\n')
            return self.login(response)
        else:
            self.log('Already logged in. Continue crawling...\n')
            return self.parse_item(response)


    def login(self, response):
        self.log("Trying to log in...\n")
        self.username = self.settings['KI_USERNAME']
        self.password = self.settings['KI_PASSWORD']
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='Form1',
            formdata={
                # needs name, not id attributes!
                'ctl04$Header$ctl01$textbox_username': self.username,
                'ctl04$Header$ctl01$textbox_password': self.password,
                'ctl04$Header$ctl01$textbox_logindaten_typ': 'Username_Passwort',
                'ctl04$Header$ctl01$checkbox_permanent': 'True',
            },
            callback = self.parse_item,
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        articles = response.xpath('//div[@id="artikel"]')
        items = []
        for article in articles:
            item = KiSpiderItem()
            item['link'] = response.url
            item['title'] = articles.xpath("div[@class='ct1']/text()").extract()
            item['subtitle'] = articles.xpath("div[@class='ct2']/text()").extract()
            item['article'] = articles.extract()
            item['published'] = articles.xpath("div[@class='biblio']/text()").re(r"(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}) PIE")
            item['artid'] = articles.xpath("div[@class='biblio']/text()").re(r"PIE \[(d+)-\d+\]")
            item['lang'] = 'de-DE'
            items.append(item)
#       return(items)
        yield items
#       what is the difference between return and yield?? found both on web.
```

When doing `scrapy crawl KiSpider`, this results in:

```
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: KiPieSpider)
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'KiPieSpider.spiders', 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 8, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['KiPieSpider.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'KiPieSpider', 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 60, 'USER_AGENT': 'KiPieSpider (info@defrent.de)', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25}
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-03-09 18:03:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=206> (referer: None)
2017-03-09 18:03:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.kiweb.de/default.aspx?pageid=202&page=1> (referer: None)
2017-03-09 18:03:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-03-09 18:03:34 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 465,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 48998,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 9, 17, 3, 34, 235000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 9, 17, 3, 33, 295000)}
2017-03-09 18:03:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Is it that the login routine should not end with a callback, but some kind of return/yield statement? Or what am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, the docs and tutorials I have seen so far only give me a vague idea of how every bit connects to the others, especially Scrapy's docs seem to be written as a reference for people who already know a lot about Scrapy.

Somewhat frustrated greetings
Christopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rules = (
        # First rule that matches a given link is followed / parsed.
        # Follow category pagination without further parsing:
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                # Extract links in the form:
                # allow=r'Default\.aspx?pageid=(202|206])&page=\d+',

                # but only within the pagination table cell:
                restrict_xpaths=('//td[@id="ctl04_teaser_next"]'),
            ),
            follow=True,
        ),
        # Follow links to category (202|206) articles and parse them:
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                # Extract links in the form:
                # allow=r'Default\.aspx?pageid=299&docid=\d+',
                # but only within article preview cells:
                restrict_xpaths=("//td[@class='TOC-zelle TOC-text']"),
            ),
            # and parse the resulting pages for article content:
            callback='parse_init',
            follow=False,
        ),
    )
```

you do not need `allow` parameter, because there is only one link in the tag selected by XPath.

I do not understand the regex in allow parameter but at least you should escape the `?`.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the unescaped ? inside the allow parameter!